# How do you add your cocoapod documentation to cocoadocs.org

Tags: cocoapods

I have created a pod file for an open source project, which has successful been added to CocoaPods. The project is here:

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC

And the spec is here:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/LinqToObjectiveC/1.0.0/LinqToObjectiveC.podspec

However, the documentation within the README.md file does not appear of CocoaDocs. I cannot find any documentation of how to achieve this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your presumption that it should "just work" is correct, but it looks like I hadn't updated  the cocoadocs' version of *pods* and it was not adding new docsets.

So, I have set off a process to do the backlog of any other podspecs that might have been missed. Normally, it takes about 20 minutes from accepting the podspec to it being on Cocoadocs.

Comment: So in short, give it a few days, you have to do nothing.

Comment: Perfect answer - thanks for that. Is the link between CocoaPods and CocoaDocs documented anywhere? If not, I'd be happy to help expand the documentation. CocoaPods is a great service, but the documentation is a little thin!

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/ this is the repo. We're re-working cocoapods' documentation ATM with a section that's begging for a mention of the link between cocoapods/cocoadocs ( https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/blob/master/guides/making-a-cocoapod.md#documenting-a-pod )